# How to Capture Text Input Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

All right, so what I want to do is make a text field that allows the user to input a number. I made so that they will have to press a button and the program will then capture that number Then I want to use that number in different parts of my code, assigning it a variable of course. The problem is that I manage to get the button to work but it is the input field that I have problems with. When I try to troubleshoot here is what happens:

1. I type in a number, 123
2. I press the button
3. Upon pressing the button the function called UpponClick starts, but the function that is supposed to be called in that function, UpponClick, doesn't start
4. Then I proceed to keep typing in that input text field and the number I input is actually shown on the output window. In fact the every time I type a number the output window shows that new number with the exclusion of the last digit.

Code:

```
    function UpponClick(){

        //trace("Click")
        CaptureText()
    }

    function CaptureText(){
        trace(1)
        iField.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, TextInputCapture);

    }

    function TextInputCapture(event:TextEvent){
        trace(2)
        var numbah:Number = Number(iField.text);
        trace(numbah)
    }
```

Comment: listen KeyboardEvent keyup event for iField to capture it or try to use event.text

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite understand that. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you should not add the same event listener more than once to the same object (like what you already do on each click of your button), this will cause a lot of troubles..

> what I want to do is make a text field that allows the user to input a number. I made so that they will have to press a button and the program will then capture that number

if I've understand you correctly, it is very simple like this :

```
// define your var outside the function so you can access it later :
var numbah:Number;

function UpponClick(){
    //trace("Click")
    numbah = Number(iField.text);
    trace(numbah);
}
```

Comment: Uhm, maybe I didn't specify, but I only click the button once. Afterwards, the program traces anything I type in it. Can you explain to me the problem I am having right there?

Also, I don't quite understand the code that you made. I can't seem to figure out how to capture the text if I don't call upon the function CaptureText()

Comment: please tell me if this is the behavior you want: "before clicking the button nothing happen, but after clicking on it for one time it should update that variable as the entered text change, without the need to click it every time to update that var".. correct?

Comment: Yes, before clicking nothing happens. Afterwards I want to save that input in a variable for further use. Ok, how about this, I will later add in so that if you click it again the input is taken once more. So, no, it should not update the variable after every keystroke.

Comment: That is exactly what my code do :) it save that input in a variable called 'numbah' so you can use it later, and will ONLY update it when you click on the button , NOT after every keystroke ...

Comment: Okay, so in order to make my code more efficient, should I move the code in this function to the TextInputCapture function? Or will there be conflicts with that? I'm also guessing that I will have to invoke CaptureText under my constructor (not part of the code here since I didn't think it was necessary).

Comment: No, this function is what you need to get the input text and store it in numbah variable. this code is the replacement for your three functions in your first question. if you post you full code maybe we can help you more

Comment: Okay, before I have to post my whole code, answer me this:

How does the text get captured in iField without the need of an eventListener? This is assuming that your code is the only thing I need in order to capture the text inside the input field.

Comment: you get the text from iField by reading its "text" property by calling "iField.text" , then we convert that string value into Number by calling "Number(iField.text)" ... and yes this code is the only thing you need , because what you need is very simple!

Comment: Wow, I just tried it for the first time, maybe I should had taken your word for it. I was just thinking **way** too much on this. Sorry if this took you too long to answer, but I am really glad you were able to explain this to me.

Comment: don't worry :) . by the way, take a look here, it is really precious resources for you if you plan to learn programing AS3 : http://www.warmforestflash.com/blog/2009/01/top-8-resources-for-learning-actionscript-3/

Comment: Well, that really is a precious resource. I will definitely look into buying some of those books. I'm not exactly looking to devout myself to AS3 since I'm only in highschool, however learning AS3 will give me fundamentals for programming (hence why I'm learning it). I wish I could give you +1 rep, but I can't because _I_ don't have 15 rep. So, I guess a thank you will have to do, =D.